# Difference between `mdutil -i off` and `mdutil -d`

Tags: macos, spotlight

From the man page:

```
    -i (on|off)    Turn indexing on or off.
    -d             Disable Spotlight activity for volume (re-enable using -i on).
```

If I execute `mdutil -i off -vvv` on a volume:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/RamDisk:
2023-04-10 20:25:46.732 mdutil[29838:28666786] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/RamDisk -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly
    Indexing disabled.
```

If I execute `mdutil -d -vvv` on a volume:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/RamDisk:
2023-04-10 20:25:33.361 mdutil[29809:28666487] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/RamDisk -> kMDConfigSearchLevelOff
    Indexing and searching disabled.
```

From my experience it seems like both disables Spotlight activity on the target volume. What is the difference between these two options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question already has the answers.

When you use the `-i` flag, it stops only the indexing.
From the status message:

> Indexing disabled.

When you use the `-d` flag, it stops both indexing and searching.  From the status message

> Indexing and searching disabled.

You can think of the `-d` flag as “disabling” Spotlight for the volume, whereas `-i` turns of indexing of the volume but still allows Spotlight to search it.

Comment: I thought Spotlight relies on indexing for searching? i.e. no indexing = no searching.

Comment: Spotlight can search non-indexed drives.  It will just do a manual search of it as if you had typed `find /Volumes/Non-Indexed/ -name foo.bar`